# Bukkit plugin with realistic shop/economy features?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I would like to add a shop plugin that lets players (ideally) purchase a shop or an npc to act as a shop that they can stock with items they've produced (i.e. the items don't come from out of thin air) and any money that they make from this shop/npc goes to their balance. I do not want this to be a global market type feature. Their customers have to physically show up to the shop to purchase these items.

It would be great if this plugin supports iConomy also. Is there anything like this?

Comment: [Sethbling made one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PiKcva8X00o) for vanilla, though requires 1.5 snapshot features and not perfect.

Comment: Etho made a version too, but I guess he didn't make a tutorial video for it.

Comment: As of 1.5 this can be accomplished without plugins through Command Blocks and the Scoreboard.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Can you do `/give` in command blocks?  I guess there isn't a good reason not to be able to do that.

Comment: @MBraedley I believe so! I've not used it, but I believe that's how items-for-XP shops use Command Blocks.

Comment: I'm trying out Bukkitforge with Essentials signs. I have a feeling that some of the Bukkit API has not been fully implemented so this may also be a dead end.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin Called [NPCTrader](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/npctrader/) in **planning** that suits your needs.

But if you can't wait for a plugin to be developed, I suggest you use [ShowCaseStandAlone](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/scs/)
along side with [Citizens](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/citizens/) This will allow users with permission to create their own shops which require customers to right-click the blocks these shops are placed on in order to buy.

ShowCaseStandAlone requires that the owners of these shops re-stock them.

Anything bought from these shops will take from the buyer, and deiliver this cash to the seller.

Comment: I'll look into this.